# How to get the size of the appdata folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to be able to get the size of the appdata folder of my Drive app. Short of keeping track of each file that I insert to/delete from the folder, I can't find a way of easily implementing this. You can get the size of the appdata in **Manage Apps** in [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) but I can't find how to get this from my app.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct API call to do this. You can do it in a slightly easier way than manually keeping track of everything.

Do a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request with the search parameter of `'appdata' in parents` to limit the results to just appdata items. Since your application can only see appdata created by itself, you don't need to worry about other applications appdata getting mixed up in there.

But wait! Before you issue that request, you can make your life even easier, faster, better, by using the fields parameter to pull back just the quota used by each item. Setting the parameter `fields=items/quotaBytesUsed` will remove all the cruft and resulting in a quicker response time. The response will be along the lines of:

```
200 OK

- Removed headers -

{
 "items": [
  {
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0"
  },
  {
   "quotaBytesUsed": "2783252"
  },
  {
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0"
  },

  ... and so on.
```

Just add them all up and voila.